# Intersection of the real line subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the introductory chapter of "Undergraduate Topology" by R. Kasriel (Dover publication) on page 13, the following exercise can be found.

Recall that $\mathbb{P}$ is the symbol for the set of positive integers. Suppose that for each $n\in \mathbb{P}$, we let $A_n=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: x\ge n\}$. Describe the sets $\bigcup\{A_n:n\in\mathbb{P}\}$ and $\bigcap\{A_n:n\in\mathbb{P}\}$.

I have some doubts about the second set:   $S= \bigcap\{A_n:n\in\mathbb{P}\}$. My first quick thought was to answer $\{\emptyset\}$ as, as $n$ going to $+\infty$, at the end $A_n$ will contain less elements than e.g. $A_1$. My feeling is that this answer is wrong as how can you assert that an infinite set like $A_1$ contains more elements than another infinite set $A_n$, even if $n$ goes to infinity. (To be honest, I have always had trouble with the question "what is infinity".)

Answer (score 0):

The number of elements is not the best starting point here. You should think instead about what the elements of $S$ could possibly be. The idea of a limiting process ("as $n$ going to $+\infty$", "even if $n$ goes to infinity") is also something of a distraction, as the question doesn't have such a limit going on. You could define one but you don't actually need to do that in order to understand $S$.

Consider the number $17.2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Is this in $S$? Well, it's in $A_4$, for example, since $17.2 \ge 4$. But it's not in $A_{213}$, since $17.2 < 213$. Because it's not in *all* of the $A_n$, it cannot be in $S$.

Now think about how that argument might apply to an arbitrary real number, not just $17.2$. Can you prove that for each number $x$, there is some $n$ such that $x \not\in A_n$?

As a final note, $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ are not the same set, so you should take care about which one you really mean.

Comment: Thx, introducing the limit was indeed a distraction.